# How can I generate a random array containing 0-9 and a-z, in APL

Tags: matrix, random, apl

`?5 5⍴CHARS` where `CHARS` is a variable containing 0-z.

The roll operator won't accept `CHARS` since it contains elements that are not non-negative integers, namely the letters a-z.

Answer (score 3):

`?5 5⍴nums` where `nums` is a list of non-negative integers would probably not give you what you want anyway, since it would reshape `nums` and then do a roll for each. Effectively, you would have `5 5⍴(?nums[1])(?nums[2])(?nums[3])`…

Instead, I assume that you want each element of your 5×5 matrix to contain a random one of the *characters* 0–9 and a–z, *with* replacement. For different assumptions, see [J. Sallé's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49242109/5306507).

As J. Sallé mentions, the uppercase alphabet is `⎕A` and in Dyalog APL we can get the lowercase with `819⌶⎕A` (819 is a [mnemonic for "BIg"](https://www.dyalog.com/blog/2016/06/i-beam-mnemonics/)) while APLX has `⎕a`. Digits are `⎕D` in both Dyalog APL and APLX, so all the 36 possible characters are `symbols←⎕D,819⌶⎕A` or `symbols←⎕D,⎕a`. On other APL systems, you may need to generate the list of characters; see footnote.

We can get the random indices of `symbols` with `indices←?5 5⍴36` and finally we do the actual indexing to get our result; `symbols[indices]`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBMWVuUn5OcWP2iY86pvqomNhaPmoZxuQ6ciVmZeSmZwKkrE3VTB91LvF2IwLqjoaKhcLAA)

As a one-liner, it is:

```
(⎕D,819⌶⎕A)[?5 5⍴36]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBBqP@qa66FgYWj7q2QZkOmpG25sqmD7q3WJsFgsA)

We can generalise this to a utility function which takes a shape as left argument and a list of elements as right argument:

```
{⍵[?⍺⍴≢⍵]}
```

Here, `≢⍵` is the number of elements, and `⍺` is the shape. This works on many systems (e.g. Dyalog, GNU and ngn). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///PygxLyU/91HbhOpHvVuj7R/17nrUu@VR5yIgL7b2/38TBRMFiBIF9cSkZHUuEwUzmMCjvqkuOhaGlo96tgGZjlzGCsYwKUMDBSMDBWMDoJgRXH9IUWmquoK6W2JOcao6F1AJVMJAwRAA) The following will work on all systems:

```
∇ array←shape Random data
  array←data[?shape⍴⍴data]
∇
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FHu0JiUVFi5aO2CcUZiQWpCkGJeSn5uQopiSWJXApwORA32h6s4lHvFiACCcRyAbX//2@iYALTpZ6YlKzOZaJgBhN41DfVRcfC0PJRzzYg05HLWMEYJmVooGBkoGBsABQzgusPKSpNVVdQd0vMKU5V5wIqgUoYKBgCAA)

---

How to generate the list of characters on any APL system:

```
⎕AV[∊-⎕IO-(⍳¨10 26)+⎕AV⍳'0a']
```

`⎕AV[`…`]` index the **A**tomic **V**ector (the character set) with:

`⎕AV⍳'0a'` the indices of "0" and "a" there

`(`…`)+` add the following to that:

`⍳¨10 26` the first 10 and the first 26 indices

`-⎕IO-` subtract 1 if `⎕IO` (**I**ndex **O**rigin) is 1, because `-(1-x)` is the same as `x-1`

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten to combine the two character vectors into one)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6pjqGRT/q6NIFsjz9dTUe9W4@tMLQQMHITFMbLAkUUDdIVI8FAA)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want a 5×5 matrix of 0-z characters, so let's do it piece by piece:

First, we create a vector of characters `CHARS←⎕A`. Notice that this vector contains the uppercase alphabet. If you want lowercase, you need to use the I-Beam operation 819, as `chars←819⌶⎕A`.

Then, since you need the numbers 0-9, we need to either add them manually to our `chars` vector, or use `⎕IO←0`, which is what I'll be doing in this case. So, with our Index Origin set to 0, we add the digits 0-9 to our vector by doing `chars,←⍳10`. The variable `chars` now returns `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Finally, we need to randomly choose those elements to populate your matrix. To do that to a mixed vector of numbers and characters, we will randomly select their *indices* instead of rolling the vector:
`chars[?≢chars]` will roll a random element of the vector. Since we need more than just one element, we will use `chars[?(≢chars)⍴≢chars]`. This will roll `≢chars`, which is 36, random elements of the vector.

After doing that, we reshape it into a 5×5 matrix. Our final code is then `5 5⍴chars[?(≢chars)⍴≢chars]`.

If you want, you can see the step-by-step on this handy website:

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##jdBNSgMxFAfwfU/xlgp2mCIjdiVFN91Y0KW4eJ15nQQyyZBE215AEBxxI67ceAXFC3iTXMS@jh1ROwwGsgjh/3sfWKp@tkRl8k8@4f5xPAk3DzG0n1A9wzl5GOuMFjCxMpcavIE46qUCrePo4WAY7t4ZGrWFR87JnCOCQJk52RQdAapS4JRZltY/15R6Y6EWN3BHPyfSlQqXP5KbzB53E6rXQdyeOzY6RU@a71cpmEsvaibjubyDuD/8f3npAXOUOuqF25eO0DpzelVMyYKZASkqSHMtqbcHuDhqqMtt48woBQgWdWaKxoGZ5UcLtNNIu6F6@61@Y/sHfzRefgIJB7qRGiAnsKR6C47bSj6eEijQW7mIVg)

Comment: @RichardAdams:  can you pls. accept the answer, so that the question is no longer shown as "open" (just tick the check-mark next to the best reply).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't

`'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'[5 5⍴36?36]`   (unique chars in 5 x 5 array)

or

`'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'[?5 5⍴36]`  (potential repeating chars)

do it?  Works in any origin, should work in every APL.